# Genetic-algorithm encoding

Tags: encoding, genetic-algorithm, knapsack-problem

I am trying to create an algorithm which I believe is similar to a knapsack-problem. The problem is to find recipes/Bill-of-Materials for certain intermediate products. There are different alternatives of recipes for the intermediate products. For example product X can either consist of 25 % raw material A + 75 % raw material B, or 50 % of raw material A + 50 % raw material B, etc. There are between 1 to 100 different alternatives for each recipe.

My question is, how best to encode the different recipe alternatives (and/or where to find similar problems on the internet). I think I have to use value encoding, ie assign a value to each alternative of a recipe. Do I have reasonable, different options?

Thanks & kind regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can encode the problem with a number chromosome. If your product has *N* ingredients, then your number chromosome has the length *N*: X={x1,x2,..,xN}. Every number xi of the chromosome represents the parts of ingredient *i*. It is not required, that the numbers sum to one.
E.g. X={23,5,0} means, you need 23 parts of ingredient 1, 5 parts of ingredient 2 and zero parts of ingredient 3.

With this encoding, crossover will not invalidate the chromosome.

Comment: I did not fully describe the problem, but you still understood it right. Thanks to both of you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a 100 dimentions variable to present  a individual just like below

```
X={x1,x2,x3,...,x100} xi∈[0,1] ∑(xi)=1.0
```

It's hard to use crossover operation.So I suggest that the offspring can just be produced by mutation operation.

Mutation operation toward parent individual 'X':

```
(1)randly choose two dimention 'xi' and 'xj' from 'X';

(2)p=rand(0,1);

(3)xj=xj+(1-p)*xi;

(4)xi=xi*p;
```